# Is it possible to Install cyanogenmod on Galaxy S2

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I have galaxy S2 which I bought two years and still is in its Prime Condition with no scratches or smudges at all. So Im planning to install New Version of Android OS on it.

I like cyanogenmod So I want to install this on my phone. I have never flashed ROM on it. It still got the same Stock version of Gingerbread 2.3.3

And yes my phone is root-ed

## Mobile info

```
Model No = GT-I9100
Android Version = 2.3.3
Kernel Version = 2.6.35.7-I9100JPKH1
Build No = Gingerbread JPKH1
```

Can someone please tell me what are the pre-requisites to install cyanogenmod

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked with the [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices#vendor=%22Samsung%22;)? It has a dedicated area for the [I9100](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/I9100_Info). Depending on which version you want to install, you can check everything there. As this is subject to change with new versions, I won't re-type all the details here :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you can install Cyanogenmod for the i9100 S2.

Get the CyanogenMod (nightly if you feel adventurous or stick with the stable since you're new at this) from http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i9100

Also, you'll need to flash the appropriate gApps package from http://goo.im/gapps

I highly recommend you read through the major posts of [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2382579) on XDA

Also, learn how to use CWM or TWRP recovery - Youtube has a number of videos. See how its done, before attempting to do it yourself, and of course - please back up your data to the cloud or to your PC / laptop / external SD card before attempting this and if possible, perform a NANDROID backup so you can revert back to how things were should the unexpected occur and you need to recover.

Comment: Thanks I will check it in this weekend. But first I have to buy some dumb phone as a backup I mean if I lose my Precious S2. I must have a backup. I will update you about progress. I'm a noob in this flashing thing

Comment: Maybe recommend a stable release not a nightly for beginners....

Comment: Which one do you recommed @p1xel ????

Comment: Try the stable first. Then if you want to try new features and test the cutting-edge versions, use the nightlies.